# Calculation of forces when rappeling

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, free-body-diagram

please excuse my English.

I do some rappeling. See attached illustration. (Never mind red marking on legs.)

[image]

Here the rope system is attached to a tree (top anchor), then goes through a rope device attached to my harness and from my harness down to the ground.

I’d like some help on how to caculate the force that my legs and feet exhibit on to the rock. I ask because it seems like the steeper the angle between the rope and my legs (beginning of rappel), the higher force on my feet. It feels like greater force than just standing straight on the ground.

I’ve read about vector forces, but I’m too old to recall any of it from school.

Comment: Try making a free body diagram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the positive x axis lie along the uphill direction, and let y be toward your head. Let $\theta$ be the angle of the rock (zero if it's horizontal). Let $\phi$ be the angle between the rope and the rock, i.e., $\phi=0$ when the rope is parallel to the rock, and $\phi\approx20$ deg in your diagram. Let $N$ be the normal force between your feet and the rock. The equations of static equilibrium are:

$$0=-mg\sin\theta+T\cos\phi$$

$$0=-mg\cos\theta+N-T\sin\phi$$

The result is

$$N=mg\cos\theta+mg\sin\theta\tan\phi.$$

So as you experienced for yourself, when $\phi$ is big, you get a bigger force between your feet and the rock.

Comment: The above assumes the rope attachment point is at the center of mass, which is close but not exact. All the forces through the person do not go through the same point, so there is a torque imbalance you have to account for also.

Answer (score 1):

So you need a **free body diagram** like the one below:

[image: fig]

Red is the tension on the rope, applied through the attachment point.

Pink is the weight of the person, applied through their center of mass.

Blue is the force through the legs, and friction from the contact point.

Not only is the vector sum of the forces zero, but also the sum of the torques about some point (arbitrary choice) also zero.

So you need to characterize the geometry of the problem and apply the above rule to have 3 equations (2 force balance, 1 torque balance) and 3 unknown forces (tension and reaction from the ground).